# UV coordinates calculation broken

Tags: 3d, uv-mapping, 3dtexture

I've tried using the classic formula of calculating barycentric coordinates.

[image]

When the plane on which you are projecting the texture is collinear to any of the base vectors it crashes with a division on zero error.

Is there any way to avoid this problem?

Comment: A work around is to add a small value to the denominator to prevent it from ever reaching zero.

Comment: I've already tried it? it doesn't work, uv coordinates get bigger than the texture

Comment: Make sure your basis vectors are linearly independent, the solution to barycentric coordinates using this formula is also the solution to a 2x2 linear system which can only be inverted when the basis vectors are linearly independent. Meaning that the vertices do not form a triangle.